# Ooyala custom preview image upload not working

Tags: rest, curl, put, ooyala

I have some issues trying to upload an [Ooyala preview image](https://help.kr.ooyala.com/video-platform/tasks/api_asset_manage_preview.html).

I'm using a PUT request and I sign the request as suggested [here](http://help.ooyala.com/video-platform/tasks/api_signing_requests.html). The issue is that when I make the CURL PUT request, I'm using CURLFile object and this won't work.

```
$data['file'] = new \CURLFile($params['image'], 'image/jpg', basename($params['image']));
$options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $data;
$queryParams = $defaultParams;
$method = 'PUT';
$bodyParams = json_encode($data);
```

Their documentation won't mention the format in which the thumbnail image should be set. Any ideas guys?